# how to delete matching lines with sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

Given input:

```
titi;0;1;2;3;1;4;5;6;7
toto;0;1;2;3;1;4;5;6;7
dada;0;1;2;3;0;4;5;6;7
```

How to delete lines that contain
`0` after the 5th semicolon?

Expected output:

```
titi;0;1;2;3;1;4;5;6;7
toto;0;1;2;3;1;4;5;6;7
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Hi! It would help if you added to your question the command that you have used until now and what are the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must do it with sed:

```
sed -Ei '/^([^;]*;){5}0/d' file.txt
```

- -E for extended regex
- -i for in-place
- the trailing `d` tells sed to delete a line if the preceeding pattern matches
- pattern is enclosed in slashes and means *0 after 5th semicolon*

Comment: that's exactly the regex that i want with sed, thank u

Answer (score 3):

Awk is better than sed to handle column based content:

```
awk -F';' '$6' file
```

Comment: 3Q awk is better

Comment: @JamesBrown I *guess* it would be "3Q=Thank you".

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F';' '$6==0{next} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try awk with semicolon as delimiter

```
awk -F";" ' $6!=0 { print } ' input_file
```

with your inputs

```
$ cat bitbyte.txt
titi;0;1;2;3;1;4;5;6;7
toto;0;1;2;3;1;4;5;6;7
dada;0;1;2;3;0;4;5;6;7

$  awk -F";" ' $6!=0 { print } ' bitbyte.txt
titi;0;1;2;3;1;4;5;6;7
toto;0;1;2;3;1;4;5;6;7

$
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i wil try it,the * is a error , it not existe in the line, i reedit the question

Comment: I have also updated the answer

Comment: thank you, it works

Comment: great!.. please consider accepting the answer